# QT socket can not connect, But hercules app can connect

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp

I have a very simple QT app, that can not connect to a hardware Board, But If I use the hercules app (https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility) , it can connect to the board and send and recive data.

here is my QT fucntion

```
QTcpSocket *socket;
socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress("192.168.1.20"),5017);

if(socket->waitForConnected(3000)){
    qDebug() << "Connected";
}else{
    qDebug() << "Sorry, can not connect";
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Try connecting to the various [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#signals) to monitor what's happening.  Also check the value returned by [`QTcpSocket::error`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should add this proxy to let it connect
socket->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);